# How to skip Ignite (de)serialization for local cache?

Tags: java, serialization, ignite, hikaricp

I'm facing issue when try store `HikariDataSource` in Ignite cache, it can't be (de)serialized by Ignite. I like Ignite's features for caches, so want to reuse it also for local needs.

```
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag$$Lambda$2327/0x00000008010b9840
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:697)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1724)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1987)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:702)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:187)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

### How to skip (de)serialization for `CacheMode.LOCAL` caches in Ignite?

Answer (score 0):

Use HashMap if you need keep a reference to the data source locally. The map doesn’t serialize objects. Ignite’s local cache always serializes records.

Comment: Could you please point me where I can read about "Ignite’s local cache *always* serializes records"?

Comment: All the objects you put in any type of cache (including the local cache) get serialized with Ignite's Binary Marshaller. Not sure if it's documented but you can always look in the source code: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/binary/GridBinaryMarshaller.java#L244